# I am getting semantic error when i am trying to run this query, not able to see any error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am getting semantic error when i am trying to run this query, not able to see any error.

Find the ssn of employee with lowest salary

```
select ssn from employee

where salary < ALL

( select salary from employee);
```

Comment: "I am getting semantic error", great!  Errors help us know what is happening.... If only we could see it somehow....

Comment: Heya @heyguys, welcome to SO! Please update your question to make it more clear. Put yourself in our shoes: without any context your text doesn't make any sense at all. Note that you can edit your question at any time to improve it.

Comment: i am using microsoft access 2010

Comment: @heyguys Just as an FYI, I believe you meant "logic error" rather than "semantic error".

Comment: @axblount-yes. you are right

Answer (score 1):

You trying to find a salary that's lower than all other salaries. That won't work because the minimum salary itself is in the table. When we reach the minimum salary, it gets compared to all other salaries in the table. But the comparison `<` will fail when we compare the minimum salary to itself.

You need to change `<` to `<=`.

```
SELECT ssn FROM employee
WHERE salary <= ALL (SELECT salary FROM employee);
```

This will return the ssn's for all employees that have the minimum salary. Equivalently,

```
SELECT ssn FROM employee
WHERE salary = (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM employee);
```

Comment: @Bohemian: I don't think so. The predicate is `<= ALL`, only the minimal value can be less than or equal to every value in the set.

Comment: @axblount: The last one, in its turn, is equivalent to `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ssn FROM employee ORDER BY salary` (although I'm not really sure if Access supports WITH TIES).